# コードブロックのフォントサイズが小さい

Tags: 討議, 完了

コードブロックのフォントサイズが小さいです。

```
#include <stdio.h>

printf("Hello");
```

英語版では 14px のようですが、日本語版では 12px です。
本文と比較しても小さいように思えるので、最低 13px くらいあったほうがよいと感じます。
どうでしょうか？

Comment: 日本語版のCSSが英語版のサイトと異なるため、改善を要求しました。改善までしばらくお待ちください。

Answer (score 3):

これまで気になっていませんでしたが、言われてみると確かに少し小さく思えます。今より大きめに調整してほしい、という意見に賛成です。

メインサイトの投稿の幾つかでCSSをいじって検証してみたところ、本文の日本語とバランスのとれた大きさとして13pxがよさそうに思いました。詳しい調整はSE社のデザイナーさんにおまかせになりますが。